# Simplify equation with two variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify the following equation with respect to r:

$-0.192852 + c1^6 (-21743.3 + 81452.7 r^{0.26297} -
379334.0 r^{0.32579} + 730090.0 r^{0.36131} + 18787.9 r^{0.38222} +
448129.0 r^{0.39968} - 749234.0 r^{0.40658} - 140538.0 r^{0.42858}) + c1^4
(-6322.12 + 35635.6 r^{0.26297} - 146992.0 r^{0.32579} + 250056.0 r^{0.36131}
+ 3992.43 r^{0.38222} + 119875.0 r^{0.39968} - 226643.0 r^{0.40658} - 33377.7
r^{0.42858}) + c1^2 (-68.6247 + 826.745 r^{0.26297} - 2475.15 r^{0.32579} +
3203.27 r^{0.36131} + 32.1743 r^{0.38222} + 1109.12 r^{0.39968} - 2378.82
r^{0.40658} - 284.589 r^{0.42858}) + c1 (2.87441 - 44.9008 r^{0.26297} +
85.3501 r^{0.32579} - 82.1351 r^{0.36131} - 0.704547 r^{0.38222} - 25.2073
r^{0.39968} + 56.1925 r^{0.40658} + 6.32419 r^{0.42858}) + c1^3 (960.464 -
7483.47 r^{0.26297} + 27501.7 r^{0.32579} - 42071.4 r^{0.36131} - 528.41
r^{0.38222} - 17197.0 r^{0.39968} + 34839.4 r^{0.40658} + 4567.47 r^{0.42858})
+ c1^5 (19176.1 - 85525.4 r^{0.26297} + 379334.0 r^{0.32579} -
693585.0 r^{0.36131} - 14090.9 r^{0.38222} - 380910.0 r^{0.39968} +
674311.0 r^{0.40658} + 112430.0 r^{0.42858}) + 0.916343 r^{0.26297}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are after, but might try

```
Collect[-0.192852 + 
  c1^6 (-21743.3 + 81452.7 r^0.26297 - 379334. r^0.32579 + 
     730090. r^0.36131 + 18787.9 r^0.38222 + 448129. r^0.39968 - 
     749234. r^0.40658 - 140538. r^0.42858) + 
  c1^4 (-6322.12 + 35635.6 r^0.26297 - 146992. r^0.32579 + 
     250056. r^0.36131 + 3992.43 r^0.38222 + 119875. r^0.39968 - 
     226643. r^0.40658 - 33377.7 r^0.42858) + 
  c1^2 (-68.6247 + 826.745 r^0.26297 - 2475.15 r^0.32579 + 
     3203.27 r^0.36131 + 32.1743 r^0.38222 + 1109.12 r^0.39968 - 
     2378.82 r^0.40658 - 284.589 r^0.42858) + 
  c1 (2.87441 - 44.9008 r^0.26297 + 85.3501 r^0.32579 - 
     82.1351 r^0.36131 - 0.704547 r^0.38222 - 25.2073 r^0.39968 + 
     56.1925 r^0.40658 + 6.32419 r^0.42858) + 
  c1^3 (960.464 - 7483.47 r^0.26297 + 27501.7 r^0.32579 - 
     42071.4 r^0.36131 - 528.41 r^0.38222 - 17197. r^0.39968 + 
     34839.4 r^0.40658 + 4567.47 r^0.42858) + 
  c1^5 (19176.1 - 85525.4 r^0.26297 + 379334. r^0.32579 - 
     693585. r^0.36131 - 14090.9 r^0.38222 - 380910. r^0.39968 + 
     674311. r^0.40658 + 112430. r^0.42858) + 0.916343 r^0.26297, r^_]
```

or you could collect on `c1`.